# Objc Regex - Parse string with groups

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to parse text file and group information before and after a ":" so that I can then know what relates to what.

I'm using the following

```
//NSString *pattern = @"\\[(.*?)\\]"; //[]
//NSString *pattern = @"(\\w+:)"; //word:
NSString *pattern =@"(\\w+:)\\[(.*?)\\]";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *input = contents; //contents being the value taken from the text file

NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myArray count]];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in myArray) {
    //NSUInteger numberOfRanges = [match numberOfRanges];
    //NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)numberOfRanges);
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    [matches addObject:[input substringWithRange:matchRange]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [matches lastObject]);
}
```

The "[]" works and the "word:" works but when I join them together I get nothing back.

Brackets (output)

```
2016-03-26 09:20:36.302 LevelBuilder[14658:550234] 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
...
2016-03-26 09:20:36.304 LevelBuilder[14658:550234] 17,1
```

Word (output)

```
2016-03-26 09:18:18.189 LevelBuilder[14464:543898] tiles:
2016-03-26 09:18:18.189 LevelBuilder[14464:543898] boxes:
2016-03-26 09:18:18.189 LevelBuilder[14464:543898] goals:
2016-03-26 09:18:18.189 LevelBuilder[14464:543898] start:
```

What am I missing in the pattern

```
NSString *pattern =@"(\\w+:)\\[(.*?)\\]";
```

The data is an example

```
tiles:
    [
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
        ,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
        ,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
        ,[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
        ,[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
        ,[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
        ,[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
        ,[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
        ,[1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
        ,[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
        ,[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        ,[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        ,[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ],
    boxes: [
            [5,6],[6,5],[10,5],[11,5],[16,4],[16,5],[16,6],[16,7]
            ],
    goals: [
            [1,8],[1,9],[1,10],[1,11],[2,10],[2,11],[3,10],[3,11]
            ],
    start: [17,1]
```

Comment: It is not quite clear. Maybe you need [`(?s)(\\w+:)\\s*\\[.*?\\](?=,\r?\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/sT5oA9/1)?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew that's got them as 4 individual matches

Comment: Does it mean you were looking for this solution?

Comment: I'd ideally want everything before : in one match and everything after : in a match so I'd have each of the four sections and then two groups per section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to match each "word" followed with its corresponding `[...]`, you can use a regex pattern containing 2 capture groups and a lookahead that will "temper" the lazy dot matching pattern:

```
@"(?s)(\\w+):\\s*\\[(.*?)\\](?=,\r?\n\\s*\\w+:|$)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sT5oA9/4)

The pattern matches:

- `(?s)`- enable a `.` to match a newline
- `(\w+):` - match and capture into Group 1 one or more  alphanumeric characters, and then match a `:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\[(.*?)\]` - match the `[...]` capturing all what is inside into Group 1 if the last `]`...
- `(?=,\r?\n\s*\w+:|$)` - is followed with the end of string (`$`) or a comma followed with a linebreak followed with 0+ whitespace symbols followed with a "word" followed with `:`.